# CSS defer to prior CSS file

Tags: css

Recently I purchased a website template, and I have never been good at CSS so I am finally trying to understand.  I have googled, but have not found if this is possible, so I am assuming its not, but I figured I would ask anyway.

CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom-style.css">
```

There are some tags in the custom-styles.css that are overriding things in bootstrap.min.css.  All good and well and working as expected.

However I am currently working on a page, and I want it to defer back to what is in boostrap.min.css for like 10 elements.  I dont want to change the custom-styles.css so is there a way I can do something like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom-style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/my-style.css">
```

and in my-style.css have something like:

```
.abc .def {
  defer to boostrap.min.css
}
```

or

```
.abc .def {
  ignore custom-style.css
}
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my-style.css override those classes with content that is in bootstrap.

example
In bootstrap you have

```css
.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

and In custom-style you have

```css
.foo {
    color: green;
}
```

then in my-style.css do something like this

```css
.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

and make it override previous declarations or simply (less recommended)

```css
.foo {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was doing. However since I hate duplicate code, I was trying to find a way just to reference the other CSS like a method or something :)

Comment: There is some other ways but none of them is worth implementing.
for example you can prepare 2x `custom-style.css` one with those classes and one without them and load them when u need.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the `body` (or main container) of your special page a distinct class, let's say `.special-page`, and then in your `custom-style.css` write your overrides like

```
:not(.special-page) .abc .def {
  /* your special style
  which doesn't get applied
  if the element is
  within .special-page */
}
```

Lear more about the `:not()` selector: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to comment out unnecessary code if you do not want to remove them. That should automatically make use of the Bootstrap code instead of the CSS. For example, if your CSS looks like:

```
.abc .def {

    Some code.....
}
```

You should comment them out like:

```
.abc .def {

    /* Your code */
}
```

Or:

```
/*

.abc .def {

    Your code.....
}

*/
```

That should work.